Contentful GraphQL collection filter for a Link field with two content types
I've Referral content type which has excludedClient field which is a Link(Many references) and it consists of Client | Client Group content types.
Both Client & Client Group content types has shortName field, which is a string, and I want to get referrals where either the client or client group name shortNames are excluded.
fragment ReferralClientFields on Client {
  shortName
}

fragment ReferralClientGroupFields on ClientGroup {
  shortName
}

query Referral {
  # add your query
  referralCollection(where: {
    excludeClient: {
      shortName_in: ["JED"]
    }
  }) {
    total
    items {
      title
      style
      context
      clientCollection(limit: 15) {
        items {
          ...ReferralClientFields
          ...ReferralClientGroupFields
        }
      }
      excludeClientCollection(limit: 30) {
        items {
          ...ReferralClientFields
          ...ReferralClientGroupFields
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I've a client group with shortName JED
And JED client group is part of the excluded clients from referral, referral1, but the above filter is not returning, referral1 even though there's an excluded client group with short name JED.

Note: If I set the excludedClient field to only have one content type which is Client Group, the above query will return the referral.
So does filter on a Link field with multiple content types not supported in contentful GraphQL? From the doc it does only mention about Link field with single content type. https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/collection-filters/sys-filters

For Link fields with a single linkContentType validation. Filtering
depth is limited to one level of relationships.


You need to move your where clause to the excludeClient section of the query
query Referral {
  referralCollection(limit: 10) {
    total
    items {
      title
      style
      context
      clientCollection(limit: 15) {
        items {
          ...ReferralClientFields
          ...ReferralClientGroupFields
        }
      }
      excludeClientCollection(limit: 30, where: {
        shortName_in: ["JED"]
      }) {
        items {
          ...ReferralClientFields
          ...ReferralClientGroupFields
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Here's the relevant docs: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/collection-filters/nested-collection-filters
